# AttributeError: 'myWindow' object has no attribute 'txtFirstName'

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to make a simple PyQT4 application that will let me show the text from two textboxes in a single message box. It's pretty straight forward, so I'm sure I'm missing something really tiny.

Thanks for your help.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        #The setGeometry method is used to position the control.
        #Order: X, Y position - Width, Height of control.
        self.resize(500,350)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sergio's QT Application.")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('menuScreenFolderShadow.png'))

        self.setToolTip('<i>Welcome</i> to the <b>first</b> app ever!')
        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Helvetica', 12))

        txtFirstName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        txtFirstName.setGeometry(35, 35, 150, 20)

        txtLastName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        txtLastName.setGeometry(35, 60, 150, 20)

        btnSubmit = QtGui.QPushButton('Say hello.', self)
        btnSubmit.setGeometry(340, 250, 150, 35)
        self.connect(btnSubmit, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clicked)

        btnQuit = QtGui.QPushButton('Exit Application', self)
        btnQuit.setGeometry(340, 300, 150, 35)

        self.connect(btnQuit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),
                    QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))

    def clicked(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, "Just dropped by to say hi!", "Welcome to this tutorial %s %s!" % (
            self.txtFirstName.text(), self.txtLastName.text()))

    def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size =  self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainForm = myWindow()
mainForm.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here's the error message I receive:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\Users\Sergio.Tapia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PyQTTests\src\pyqttests.py",
>   line 36, in clicked
>       self.txtFirstName.text(), self.txtLastName.text()))
>   AttributeError: 'myWindow' object has
>   no attribute 'txtFirstName'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `__init__`, where `txtLastName` is created. It's not created as a class member, but rather as a local variable inside the `__init__` method. To make it a class member you can later refer to, use `self.`:

```
    self.txtFirstName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
    self.txtFirstName.setGeometry(35, 35, 150, 20)

    self.txtLastName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
    self.txtLastName.setGeometry(35, 60, 150, 20)
```

Comment: @Serg: you're welcome. I suggest you ramp-up on Python itself a little bit - it will really help you understand and effectively use PyQt as well